# How to Dismiss a popup with a click of a button in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm creating something with kivy that if a user inputs something wrong a popup would come out.

A popup would come out as expected but the closing part is where i am getting stuck. if i click the "understand" button to close the popup. it gives me an error.

This is my python code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

# define the kivy version
kivy.require('2.2.1')


# define the screens
class FirstWindow(Screen):
    # Instantiating some variables
    # these variables should also be in the kv.file to build (should be identical)
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)
    re_password = ObjectProperty(None)

    # the popup
    def PopupWindow(self):
        show = PopupWindow()

        popupwindow = Popup(
            title="Warning!", content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400)
        )
        popupwindow.open()
        show.popup =popupwindow

    # button for logging in
    def log_in(self):
        # If the input is not empty
        # strip() method returns a non-empty string if there is input,
        # and an empty string if there is no input,
        # the condition will evaluate to True only if all fields have input.
        if self.username.text.strip() and self.password.text.strip() == self.re_password.text.strip():
            print("Greetings! ", self.username.text)
            print("your password is: ", self.password.text)
            self.manager.current = "second"
            # to check if the passwords are the same
        if self.password.text.strip() != self.re_password.text.strip():
            print("please check your inputs: ")
            print("your input for password: ", self.password.text)
            print("your input for re_password: ", self.re_password.text)
            self.PopupWindow()
        else:
            # to check if required fields are inputted by the user
            if not self.username.text.strip():
                print("Username is required!")
            if not self.password.text.strip():
                print("Password is required!")
            if not self.re_password.text.strip():
                print("Re-password is required!")


    # button for clearing inputs
    def clear_input(self):
        self.username.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""
        self.re_password.text = ""
        print("cleared!")

    pass
class SecondWindow(Screen):
        def back_button(self):
            self.manager.current = "create"


class ThirdWindow(Screen):

    pass
class PopupWindow(Screen):
    def understood(self, popup):
        popup.manager.current.dismiss()
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

# instantiate your app [an object just means to create it]
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # define kv.file
        kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

and this is my code in kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:
    ThirdWindow:
    PopupWindow

<FirstWindow>:
    name: "create"
    # the variables from py file
    # these are to be used as ids in TextInput
    username: username
    password: password
    re_password: re_password


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: 5
        padding: 50
        cols: 1
        Image:
            source: "447.png"
            size_hint_y: "0.1dp"
        Label:
            text: "User_Login"
            size_hint_y: "0.1dp"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            padding: 15

            Label:
                text: "User_Name: "
            TextInput:
                id: username
                multiline: "False"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            padding: 15

            Label:
                text: "Enter_Password: "
            TextInput:
                id: password
                multiline: "False"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            padding: 15


            Label:
                text: "**Re_Enter_Password: "
            TextInput:
                id: re_password
                multiline: "False"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            spacing: 10

            Button:
                text: "Clear"
                on_press: root.clear_input()

            Button:
                text: "Submit"
                on_press:
                    root.log_in()

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: 5
        padding: 50
        Label:
            text: "You just Logged in!"
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            on_press:
                root.back_button()

<PopupWindow>:
    name: "popup"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "please check your password"
        Button:
            text: "understood"
            on_release:
                root.understood()
```

after clicking the "understood" button.  i was expecting the popup to simpy close but it gave me an error:

```
 in <module>
     root.understood()
 TypeError: PopupWindow.understood() missing 1 required positional argument: 'popup'
```

Does it mean i need the popup to be referenced? I don't know much. It's been maybe 40 minutes or so and i am mental blocked.

I'm a slow learner so i would greatly appreciate it for the help.

Comment: Try looking at [Popup](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call `dismiss()` on the `Popup` instance:

```
class PopupWindow(Screen):
    def understood(self):
        # popup.manager.current.dismiss()
        self.popup.dismiss()
```